# Copy Data from Input Sheet to Log Sheet in VBA Using Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with laboratory data.

An input page has two columns one for Influent values and one for Effluent values.
The Influent starts with B13 to lRow and Effluent starts with C13 to lRow.
The input page has a combobox called cbSheet so the user can select which facility log sheet to transfer this data to.

I have written a macro that should copy and transpose Influent data from the Input sheet to the sheet selected in the combobox and paste it after the last used row.
Next the macro should copy the Effluent data and paste it directly below the Influent data on the same sheet.

I would like the macro to alternate copying influent transposing and pasting to the sheet selected in the combobox followed by the effluent.

There should be something like this on the log sheet:

```
Influent "DATA"   
Effluent "DATA"  
Influent "DATA"  
Effluent "DATA"
```

I get an error trying to reference the cbSheet combobox.

> Variable Not Defined

Also, I only have the influent data selected.
How do I include the effluent so they alternate as new data is added every week?

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow1 As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    Dim lRow3 As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
    lRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lRow2 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If ws1.Range("A8").Value <> "" Then
        Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(cbSheet.Value)
        lRow3 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With ws1
            .Range("A13" & lRow1).Copy
            ws2.Range("A15" & lRow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What type of combobox?  Forms, or ActiveX?

Comment: FYI `.Range("A13" & lRow1).Copy` seems off - `.Range("A" & lRow1).Copy` or `.Cells(lRow1, "A").Copy`

Comment: Active X combobox. Thanks for all your help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: missed the `Transpose` bit...

Try this:

```vb
Sub Transfer()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws2 As Worksheet, wsInput As Object 'not As Worksheet
    Dim cDest As Range, wsName, rngDest, v
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsInput = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    wsName = wsInput.cbSheet.Value
    If Len(wsName) > 0 Then
        If wsInput.Range("A8").Value <> "" Then
            Set cDest = wb.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            
            With wsInput.Range("B13:C" & wsInput.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
                v = Application.Transpose(.Value)
                With cDest.Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count)
                    .Value = v
                    .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
                End With
            End With
        
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "First select a destination worksheet from the drop-down list!", _
               vbExclamation, "No destination selected"
    End If
End Sub
```

You can't declare `wsInput` as `Worksheet`, becuase the "out of the box" Worksheet object model does not include a member named "cbSheet".  By declaring it `As Object`  the member gets resolved at run-time instead of compile-time.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you so much, the code is transferring the data, however it's not transposing the Input sheet columns to rows in the log sheet. Everything is copying to Row B, down the column. Influent should be Row 15 on the log sheet and Effluent should be Row 16 on the Log Sheet. Everyday new data is added I am hoping these columns will be transposed and added to the log sheet following the previously added influent and effluent rows.

Comment: Sorry missed the `Transpose` bit -see edit above

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you so much, absolutely perfect.

Comment: One last question, would there be a way to validate in the initial If statement whether or not cbSheet has a value and if not present a msgbox?

Comment: wb.Worksheets(wsInput.cbSheet.Value) <> "" Then; I tried this however it gave an error message.

Comment: One more update added...

Comment: Is there a way to add thin borders and background color the cells copied to the new sheet? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Try recording a macro while doing that and then use that as a starting point for your modifications.

Comment: So I have used the following code, which I got it to work on another part of the worksheet with a single line. Having these two lines is throwing me off.   lRow = wsInput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lCol = wsInput.Cells(15, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
            
           Set iRange = wsInput.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)
            
            For Each iCell In iRange
                iCell.BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlMedium
            Next iCell

Comment: Try the edit above

Comment: Your an absolute genius, thank you so very much for all your help. I really appreciate it.